# google cloud armor: don't get targets for applying policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I am working on setting up a load balancer and cloud armor. When setting up cloud armor, the load balancer backend service does not show up as a target. So unable to choose a target for the cloud armor policy.

I have followed all the steps as per this:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto#mig

The steps are:

1. create a instance group (has 2 VMs, autoscaling off, all VM in same region, zone)
2. added health check to the instance group (http, status shows green/healthy)
3. create a regional load balancer - https on the front end, http for backend services
4. In cloud armor, in "Apply policy to new target" - in the drop down, do NOT see the backend service associated with the load balancer that was created successfully. so unable to select a target.

any help on the above would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to make sure that you have completed the setup of your backend in [this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto#load-balancer) part of the documentation. You can also provide a screenshot of your LB details in your post and just mask the ID addresses you use.

Answer (score 0):

@laks :

As of today, Google Cloud Armor is supported only for Global Loadbalancers.
Check the load balancer you're using, I strongly feel that you're using a regional load balancer, that's why it's not showing you on the targets.
Prefer using GLB and that should be the fix.

Thanks
Manoj Pachigolla